# Title of the current parent structure

Tags: structure

I want to display the current title of the parent structure inside the child template.

How would I do that?

- Parent (Title: Bla)
- - Child (Here I want to display `Bla`)
- Parent (Title: Blablu)
- - Child (Here I want to display `Blablu`)

I tried something like (in the child template):

```
{% set parentTitle = craft.entries.section('structure').level(1).title %}
<h1>{{ parentTitle }}</h1>
```

But that doesn't even result in an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to get the top most parent entry of a child entry in a structure, you can use [`ancestorOf`](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#ancestorOf).

```
{% set parent = craft.entries.ancestorOf(entry).level(1).first() %}
<h1>{{parent.title}}</h1
```