# How to get Structure parent title and ancestors on search results page

Tags: structure, search

I'm having trouble getting the Structure parent title on a search results page.

I followed [these instructions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11614/title-of-the-current-parent-structure/11617#11617) but I'm getting a "Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a null variable" error.

In the following code the all ancestors do print except the first level Structure title.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{# {% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %} #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section().search(query).order('score') %}


<ul class="list-unstyled">
  {% for entry in entries %}
 <li>
  <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
  {% set parent1 = entry.getAncestors().level(1) %}
  {% for item in parent1 %}
      / {{ item.title }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% set parent2 = entry.getAncestors().level(2) %}
  {% for item in parent2 %}
      / {{ item.title }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% set parent3 = entry.getAncestors().level(3) %}
  {% for item in parent3 %}
    / {{ item.title }}
  {% endfor %}
 </li>
  {% endfor %}
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in [getSection()](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getSection)

```
<li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

  {% set section = entry.getSection() %}
   {{ section }}
  {% set parent1 = entry.getAncestors() %}
   {% for item in parent1 %}
    / {{ item }}
   {% endear %}

</li>
```